# Windows Tensorflow could not restore checkpoint. "Access is denied."

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run [SSD-Tensorflow](https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow) project using Tensorflow 1.1. When I try to restore the checkpoint file in cell 7 of [ssd_notebook.ipynb](https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow/blob/master/notebooks/ssd_notebook.ipynb) I get the following error:

`Unable to open table file D:\Projects\SSD-Tensorflow\checkpoints\ssd_300_vgg.ckpt: Unknown: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: D:\Projects\SSD-Tensorflow\checkpoints\ssd_300_vgg.ckpt : Access is denied.
; Input/output error
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_70 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save_1/Const_0, save_1/RestoreV2_70/tensor_names, save_1/RestoreV2_70/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: save_1/RestoreV2_31/_29 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_421_save_1/RestoreV2_31", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]`

Essentially,

`ckpt_filename = '../checkpoints/ssd_300_vgg.ckpt'
saver = tf.train.Saver()
session = tf.Session()
saver.restore(session, ckpt_filename)`

is throwing a `Access Denied` error when trying to restore a checkpoint file. I ensured that I can read and write from that folder and even tried running the notebook as an Admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to have the same problem and now I have found what is wrong.
I think it's because you didn't make the save_path right.
Following is my way to make it right. Hope this would help you.

The checkpoint files include two files: the xxx.index and xxx.data.

The variable save_path in function saver.restore() should be the 'xxx'.

For example,I saved my checkpoint in the direction ckpt_path, and there are three files:

- 'model-20170508-212349.ckpt-17873.data-00000-of-00001'
- 'model-20170508-212349.ckpt-17873.index'
- 'model-20170508-212349.meta'

and the script should be like this:

```
saver.restore(session,'ckpt_path/model-20170508-212349.ckpt-17873')
```